# Passing HTTP Header to the Service Reference

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ASP.Net MVC 5. Have added service reference using VS 2017, when i pass header (UserId) from the AJAX Jquery call to the Controller, the header information is not carried forward to the webservice call being made to the Server from the class library. I am new to .Net and I may be missing something here. I have seen the posts for IClientInterpreter and other stuff, but they seem very complex I think there may be a simple solution that i may be missing, hence I am looking for your expert comments on this.